# Serialize a Java object using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jaxb

I have the following two classes hierarchy:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name="Dictionary",propOrder={"description"})
public class DictionaryDto implements Serializable, Descriptionable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @XmlAttribute(required=true)
    private String id;

    @XmlElement(name="Description")
    private String description;

    public DictionaryDto() {
    }

    public DictionaryDto(String id, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
    }

    //getters and setters follows...
}

public class DictionaryProvinceDto extends DictionaryDto {

    private String code;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public DictionaryProvinceDto () {
        super();
    }

    public DictionaryProvinceDto (String id, String description, String code) {
        super(id, description);
        this.code= code;
    }

    //getters and setters follows...
}
```

where Descriptionable is an interface declaring the only method `String getDescription()`

I am trying to serialize in XML an object of type DictionaryProvinceDto but I am getting

```
<Province id="030">
    <code>AN</code>
</Province>
```

Desired output:

```
<Province id="030">
    <code>AN</code>
    <description>my funny province</description>
</Province>
```

Does anybody can explain why I don't obtain what I expect?

Comment: if you want to just ignore the field use `@XmlTransient` annotation on top of `description` field

Comment: Why do you put the `@XmlElement(name="Description")` at the `description` in the first place if you don't want it to be serialized?

Comment: No, I want the description field to be serialized. Maybe I was not very clear on that point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Province")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name="DictionaryProvince")
public class DictionaryProvince extends Dictionary {
    @XmlElement(required=true)
    private String code;
    // ...
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name="Dictionary",propOrder={"description"})
public class Dictionary {  // no need for Serializable
    // ... as before
}

@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {
    private final static QName _dict_QNAME = new QName("", "dict");
    public ObjectFactory() {
    }
    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "", name = "Province")
    public JAXBElement<DictionaryProvince> 
    createDictionaryProvince(DictionaryProvince value) {
        return new JAXBElement<DictionaryProvince>(_dict_QNAME, DictionaryProvince.class, null, value);
    }
}
```

And finally the marshalling code:

```
DictionaryProvince dp = new DictionaryProvince( "id", "prov", "code" );
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( PACKAGE );
Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
JAXBElement<DictionaryProvince> jbe;
jbe = wrap( null, "Province", dp );
m.marshal( jbe, sw );
```

And method wrap:

```
<T> JAXBElement<T> wrap( String ns, String tag, T o ){
    QName qtag = new QName( ns, tag );
    Class<?> clazz = o.getClass();
    @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
    JAXBElement<T> jbe = new JAXBElement( qtag, clazz, o );
    return jbe;
}
```